# ionic framework hide ion-tabs on certain tab state

Tags: ionic-framework

I've been trying to find a solution but I can't find any.
I'll use basic examples so anyone who knows ionic can understand my problem well.

`ionic start myApp tabs` will create a new project with tabs ready to go.

Those tabs are Dashboard, Chat and Settings.
When you go to the `Chat Tab` you will then select a person to view its chat content (which directs you to the `Chat-Detail` Page in actuallity)
I wanted to hide the `ion-tabs` directive when I go to the `chat-detail` page so I can force the user to use the `Back` button instead of clicking anything on the `ion-tabs`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put : you will have a hard time doing that. At best it will not look good, IF you succeed to hide using css (I did it, and really, it's not pretty). Basically you would need to define a variable on the parent scope, that changes when entering the chat-detail state, and bind it to ng-class directives on multiple elements (the ion-tabs to hide it, the ion-content to translate it up to cover the area where the tabs were, and add some transition to make it not too brutal).

The logical thing to do would be to have the chat-detail state not being a child of the state containing the tabs. The problem you will have, though, is that there is a huge bug going to / from tabbed state. See details here : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2997

At the end of this discussion you can find some posts by Jason and Jerrybels (that would be me), that could lead you on the right way to do it. Basically, you will have to get rid of the ion-tabs directive, and use [Ionic's CSS for tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs) instead, doing all the states manipulations yourself.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can use "hidden" attribute of ion-tab like this -

```
<ion-tab hidden={{condition}}" />
```

Using this we can show/hide tab.